# Substack in brackets

Tags: brackets, substack

I have the following code:

```
\begin{dcases}
\left\lbrace  j\in C/\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\bigcup_{\substack{\scriptscriptstyle \forall c' \text{ s.t.\@}\\
\scriptscriptstyle \pi_{ic'}(\alpha)>\pi_{ic}(\alpha)}}
\!\!\!\! C'\ \middle|\ \omega_{ij}(\alpha)>0 \right\rbrace  & \mbox{if } \mathtt{max}_p(S_0) = \emptyset\\[5pt]

\left\lbrace  j\in C/\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\bigcup_{\substack{\scriptscriptstyle \forall c' \text{ s.t.\@}\\
\scriptscriptstyle c'\in\mathtt{isucc}(C),\\
\scriptscriptstyle \nexists c'' \text{ s.t.\@} \\
\scriptscriptstyle \pi_{ic''}(\alpha)>\pi_{ic'}(\alpha)}}\!\!\!\! 
C'\ \middle|\ \omega_{ij}(\alpha)>0 \right\rbrace &  \mbox{otherwise}
\end{dcases}&&
```

It produces the following results:

[image]

The whole thing is very ugly. How can it be cleaned?

In particular, in each case in `dcases`, the curely brackets take up too much space. Maybe if they did not expand to the top of the equations as much as the bottom (as needed because of `substack`), it would have looked cleaner.

Also please suggest any better way to produce this result in a cleaner form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need that the braces cover also those complicated conditions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
\biggl\lbrace
  j\in C\bigg/
  \mspace{-18mu}
  \bigcup_{\scriptscriptstyle\substack{
    \forall c' \text{ s.t.}\\
    \pi_{ic'}(\alpha)>\pi_{ic}(\alpha)
  }}
  \mspace{-18mu}
  C' \biggm| \omega_{ij}(\alpha)>0
\biggr\rbrace
  & \text{if } \mathtt{max}_p(S_0) = \emptyset
\\[5pt]
\biggl\lbrace  
  j\in C\bigg/
  \mspace{-18mu}
  \bigcup_{\scriptscriptstyle\substack{
    \forall c' \text{ s.t.}\\
    c'\in\mathtt{isucc}(C),\\
    \nexists c'' \text{ s.t.}\\
    \pi_{ic''}(\alpha)>\pi_{ic'}(\alpha)
  }}
  \mspace{-18mu}
  C' \biggm| \omega_{ij}(\alpha)>0
\biggr\rbrace
  & \text{otherwise}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for mspace. Much better than \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I fill prefer the following form:
[image]

It is obtained width following code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{r|l}
$j\in \dfrac{C}{\bigcup\limits_{\substack{
                        \forall c' \text{ s.t.}\\
                        \pi_{ic'}(\alpha)>\pi_{ic}(\alpha)
                        \hphantom{''}%just for centering
                        }} C'}$
    & $\omega_{ij}(\alpha)>0$
    \end{tabular}   & \text{if } \mathtt{max}_p(S_0) = \emptyset    \\
    \begin{tabular}[t]{r|l}
$j\in \dfrac{C}{\bigcup\limits_{\substack{
                        \forall c' \text{ s.t.}\\
                        c'\in\mathtt{isucc}(C),\\
                        \nexists c'' \text{ s.t.}\\
                        \pi_{ic''}(\alpha)>\pi_{ic'}(\alpha)
                        }}  C'}$ 
    & $\omega_{ij}(\alpha)>0$
    \end{tabular}   & \text{otherwise}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

If you prefer to have each part of cases in curly braces, than before and after each tabular add `\left{` and `right}` respectively.

I hope that I understand your equation ...

**Edit:**
With added `array` package (in poreamble), you can rewrite both `tabular` environments in:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{$}r<{$}|>{$}l<{$}}
```

and than omit `$ ... $` in each cell of tabular. This simplify writing your equation a little bit.